# Display all approved Posts belonging to a category Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display all APPROVED posts belonging to a category from the slug passed in from URL.

I have the **`approved`** column in my **`posts`** table and I have the following code in my controller done up.

```
public function cats($category){
 $posts = PostCategory::where('category_slug', $category)->first()->posts;
 dd($posts);
}
```

The code above works fine and it returns all posts related to that category, but I am trying to return only posts that have been approved, not all of them. How do I accomplish this?

Also, I am trying to count the number of posts from that category that have been approved.
I currently have this: `{{ $category->posts->count() }}`. It works fine, but counts all the posts. I am only looking to return the count of approved posts.

Hopefully someone sees this and helps out. Thanks!

Comment: Well, how do you store if it's approved? You should look into Laravel's "scopes".

Comment: You have **approved** column in **posts** model, but this is `PostCategory` model. Hope both model has a relationship each other. If so, then please post the relationship, so we can help

Comment: The code was done in the Posts controller. And posts have a belongsTo relationship with Category and category hasmany posts. All of this part works fine. I just want to include posts that are approved instead of returning all the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new relationship on the Category model, with your extra `where` included:

```
public function approvedPosts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->where('approved', 'true');
}
```

This permits you to do:

```
$posts = PostCategory::where('category_slug', $category)->first()->approved_posts;
```

Comment: You rock! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Category Model Posts Function :

```
public function posts()
{
     $posts = Post::where('category_slug', $this->slug)->where('status', 1)->get();
     return $posts;
}
```

On Controller

```
    $posts = PostCategory::where('category_slug', $slug)->firstorFail()->posts();
    return view('xxxxx', compact('posts'));
```

Comment: the 'approved' field is on the posts table, not the categories

Comment: The ‘approved’ column is in the posts table. The category slug is what I am getting from the route, so, I fetch all posts related to that slug (this part works fine). But I am only looking to return the posts that have their approval status set to true.